# Can I block with Myth Realized if I attacked with it on my turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Myth Realized](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394632) lets you pay {W} to turn it into a creature until end of turn. My question is...  if I turn it into a creature on my turn and attack, can I also block with it on my opponents turn?

Comment: You might want to have a read through the [Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf), which should cover things like this - unless the point of your question was actually to ask "can enchantments be tapped, or does it untap when it stops being a creature?"

Comment: "can enchantments be tapped, or does it untap when it stops being a creature?" was indeed the "point" of my question. But then if you answer the question as asked you're also presumably answering the other questions my question was hinting at. What's next? If I ask a math question about 90 degree angles will you get on my case because I didn't ask about right angles (even though they're the same thing)?

Comment: It might be better to directly ask each of your hinted questions as a separate site question.

Comment: I thought you were asking if it would still be a creature, because you didn't mention using the ability again to make it a creature again. So your question isn't written clearly.

Comment: @neubert It's usually best to just be specific: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I'm not getting on your case, it's just pretty hard to read minds over the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  As a creature, it still taps to attack, so barring some other action, it will remain tapped (turning it back into a creature will not untap it) and can't block on your opponents turn.

Comment: Not only will it be tapped, it will not be a creature anymore. It stops being a creature at the end of the turn; the question didn't say anything about turning it into a creature again.

Comment: @Gendolkari - yeah, that's just not much of an obstacle with a card like an enchantment that becomes a creature for 1 mana.  But the question wasn't explicit, and I guess that's been sussed out above.

Comment: True, but the issue is that as worded, it sounds like the OP may not understand when it stops being a creature.

Answer (score 1):

No because he will remain tapped.